# How to deploy cesium-starter-app in Flask

Tags: html, flask, web, cesiumjs

I have a small web project running on a python flask microframework.
I have several .html pages working in the flask server with the @app.route method

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

and I want to be able to visualize a cesium-starter-app index.html as one of them to use it as a visualizer of some properties, i.e. position of a spacecraft.

To test if the server allows the cesium app to be displayed I have replaced one of the .html files of my web project with the index.html one provided in the project https://github.com/pjcozzi/cesium-starter-app and updated the browser but the page is blank.

I also copied the Source and ThirdParty folders and the server.js file to the same directory where the .html is located to see if this do the trick but it doesnt work.

Could you please advice me on how to proper deploy the cesium-starter-app (or any other cesium implementation that works) inside a Flask web?
Thanks in advance!